# If $ f\geq0 $ and $ \intop_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x\right) $ converge, and $ \intop_{0}^{\infty}f'\left(x\right) $ converge, does it mean that:

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $ f $ be non negative function, and differntiable such that $ f' $ is continious and $ \intop_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x\right),\intop_{0}^{\infty}f'\left(x\right) $ both converge.

Is it true that $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f'\left(x\right)=0 $?

I know that $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=0 $ for sure in this conditions. But Im not sure how to tell something about the limit of the deriviative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No.$\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous, then $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^\infty f'(t) \, dt$ exists.  Since  $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ exists what can the limit be? OP is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x \geqslant 1$, take $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{2+\sin x^3}{x^2}$ and **extend** as a C1 function on $[0,1]$.

Note that $f'(x) = 3 \cos x^3 - (4+2 \sin x^3)/x^3$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: The counterexample as I said above has this form on $[1,\infty)$ where the integrals converge.  You just append a C1 piece for the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx  + \int_1^\infty \frac{2 + \sin x^3}{x^2} \, dx $ = finite integral over $[0,1] + 2.19731...$ and similarly for $\int_0^\infty f'(x) \, dx$.

Comment: What is a C1 function?

Comment: @FreeZe: That is continuously differentiable. In other words, a differentiable function with a continuous derivative. This is one of OPs conditions that $f$ and $f'$ are continuous. The integral over $[0,1]$ is always finite for such functions and does not require further specification for the above counterexample to work  (where I define the function explicitly on $[1,\infty)$.)